# How to check instanceof in mako template?

Tags: python, mako

I have a variable myvariable that I want to use in a Mako template. I want to be able to somehow check its type before doing anything with it. What is the syntax to check that sort of information? I know python has typeof and instanceof, but is there some equivalent in Mako or how would you do it?

Pseudocode below:

```
% if myvariable == 'list':
// Iterate Throuh the List
   %for item in myvariable:
         ${myvariable[item]}
   %endfor
%elif variabletype == 'int':
// ${myvariable}

%elif myvariable == 'dict':
// Do something here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isinstance()`:

```
>>> from mako.template import Template
>>> print Template("${isinstance(a, int)}").render(a=1)
True
>>> print Template("${isinstance(a, list)}").render(a=[1,2,3,4])
True
```

UPD. Here's the usage inside if/else/endif:

```
from mako.template import Template
t = Template("""
% if isinstance(a, int):
    I'm an int
% else:
    I'm a list
% endif
""")


print t.render(a=1)  # prints "I'm an int"
print t.render(a=[1,2,3,4])  # prints "I'm a list"
```